# For fallen arches - supportive or flat shoes

Tags: orthotics, podiatry, footwear, flat-feet-fallen-arches

Some podiatrists recommend well cushioned shoes with lots of support for people with fallen arches. However, some say that you should wear flat, firm shoes with no support so the foot muscles get enough exercise and get strong enough to support the arch.
What do you think?